# Why is this grep group failing

Tags: macos, bash, grep

I am trying to do something like this on my OSX terminal

```
> grep -i "((\D*)ful)" ./Myfile.rtf
```

The above statement fails however when I do this

```
> grep -i "\D*ful" ./Myfile.rtf
```

it passes -  does grep have an issue with regex groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since basic grep uses BRE, you need to use `\(..\)` for capturing group.

```
grep -i "\(\(\D*\)ful\)" ./Myfile.rtf
```

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem when this sort of thing happens is that the special characters are or are not special. In this case, I think the brackets are not special unless you quote them, so:

```
> grep -i "\(\(\D*\)ful\)" ./Myfile.rtf
```

would probably work better.

[One of the irritations of regex is the variation that has developed in exactly how they are written...]